# It is corret usage to create a tab for mithril?

Tags: mithril.js

I want to create a simple `Tab` but I think it is strange for my using:

```js
var root = document.body
      var index = {
         view: () => index.html,
         html: m('div', { id: 'div1' }, [
            [
               (function () {
                  let value = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
                  let output = []

                  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                     output.push(m('input', {
                        class: (function () {
                           if (i == 0) return "onit"
                        })(),
                        type: 'button',
                        value: value[i],
                        onclick: function () {
                           let div1 = document.getElementById("div1")
                           let btn = div1.getElementsByTagName("input")
                           let div1_div = div1.getElementsByTagName("div")
                           let _this = this
                           let num = (function () {
                              for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
                                 if (btn[i] == _this) {
                                    return i
                                 }
                              }
                           })()

                           for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
                              btn[i].className = ""

                           }
                           this.className = "onit"

                           for (let i = 0; i < div1_div.length; i++) {
                              div1_div[i].setAttribute("style", "dispaly:none")
                           }

                           div1_div[num].setAttribute("style", "display:block")
                        }
                     }))
                  }
                  return output
               })()
            ],
            [
               (function () {
                  let arr = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]
                  let output = []
                  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                     output.push(m("div", { style: (the => i == 0 ? "display:block" : undefined)() }, arr[i]))
                  }
                  return output
               })()
            ]
         ])
      }
      m.route(root, "/index", {
         "/index": index
      })
```

Is there any other simple way to achieve this?
If I click the button, the style of button will change and the display of all "div" will be changed. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8qL7.png)

Comment: Hi Blue, there's a lot of ways in which the code could be simplified, but StackOverflow isn't the right place to discuss it - it's more of Q&A site where somebody has a problem where there could be judged to be a 'correct' technical answer to the question. Because the question here is about relative simplicity, there are any number of subject answers that could go into any amount of depth. I recommend heading to the [Mithril chatroom](https://gitter.im/mithriljs/mithril.js), where myself and others would be delighted to help you!

Comment: emmmm……I think it is the forum here. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

In mithril.js views you can only use expressions, `for`-loops, `if`s and so on are no expressions and only possible the way you did it. Nevertheless there are other ways to achieve this

Loops can be achieved using the functional counterparts

```
let values = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
let output = []
function(){
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    output.push(m('span', value)
  }
  return output
}()
```

can be written as

```
values.map(value => m('span', value)
```

`if`-Statements can be written using the ternary expression

```
function() {
  if (condition) {
    return 'this'
  } else {
    return 'that'
  }
}()
```

just use

```
condition ? 'this' : 'that'
```

You can also use view functions if your view code gets to deeply nested and you need custom logic:

```
function someOtherView(someData) {
  if (someData.shouldBeShown) {
    return someData.text
  }
}

function someView() {
  ...
              someOtherView(someData)
  ...

}
```

This also makes your views more readable.